# Wordpress error - Uncaught TypeError: e.dispatchEvent is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, error-handling, console

I am getting this error in the console:

```
/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.min.js?ver=3.6.1

TypeError: e.dispatchEvent is not a function 

at Events.dispatch (/wp-content/plugins/elementor/assets/js/frontend.min.js?ver=3.8.0:2:34576) 
at Frontend.init (/wp-content/plugins/elementor/assets/js/frontend.min.js?ver=3.8.0:2:8700) 
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (/wp-content/plugins/elementor/assets/js/frontend.min.js?ver=3.8.0:2:9035) 
at e (/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.min.js?ver=3.6.1:2:30038) 
at t (/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.min.js?ver=3.6.1:2:30340)
```

I know that there are many questions addressing this error but none of them is solving my issue.

Answers on those similar questions that did not fix my issue:

- Jquery being loaded twice - not in my case.
- Use of jQuery vs $ in theme - not in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try below code once?

Add After all the Jquery script tag's

```
<script>jQuery.noConflict();</script>
```

Please let me know if you find any issues.

Thanks.

Comment: This is already present at the end of this file:
/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.min.js